# CSS - Can't figure where excess horizontal scrolling is coming from?

Tags: css, html, scale

I have been trying to modify a responsive website that uses media queries.

When the website is scaled to mobile size it requires horizontal scrolling no matter what size you make the screen.

I have tried changing everything that I think might be causing this but can't get to the bottom of it.

Here is the link to the website and the media query css file

http://stopcry.in
http://stopcry.in/styles/media-queries.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding padding on a width:100% for #sidebar and #container so total width will always be above 100%; Try using percent values also for padding so the total width will be 100%; something like this:

```
#sidebar{width:90%; padding:25px 5% 10px}
#container{width:90%; padding:5%;}
```

Comment: Or, you can use `box-sizing: border-box` and still use padding on an element with 100% width ;)

Answer (score 0):

Padding is added on top of % width/heights. So when you have 100% width with padding it exceeds 100%.

A quick fix would be `box-sizing: border-box` to change the box model but you may want to go another route.

http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing

*Edit: seems I am late to post...*

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css

```
*{
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;

}
```

or

```
.Your_Container{
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```